# Java Battleship check Hit location

Tags: java, arrays

I am creating a battleship game and I am having an issue with shooting at the same location.  I have a single array for the shoot method, holding in `shoot[0]` for the rows and `shoot[1]` for the columns.  I am trying to create a 2d array to store the location of `shoot[0]` for the rows and the `shoot[1]` for the columns; then with that double array I am able to check already hit location.  The thing is that, I am not sure if you can store signals array in the location in the double array[row][col].

After working on this code for a while, I have got the 2D array to store the values of the Shoot[0] and shoot[1].  But I do not know if i am doing it correctly:

```
    public static void shoot(int[] shoot, int[][] ships){
    int[][] check = new int[6][6];
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter AI Row: ");
    shoot[0] = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter AI Column: ");
    shoot[1] = input.nextInt();

    while((shoot[0] <= 0 || shoot[1] <= 0) ||(shoot[0] == 0 && shoot[1] == 0) || (shoot[0] > 5 || shoot[1] > 5)){
      System.out.println("You must enter a location greater than 0 and NOT over 5! ");
      System.out.print("Enter Row: ");
      shoot[0] = input.nextInt();

      System.out.print("Enter Column: ");
      shoot[1] = input.nextInt();
    }    

    int temp1 = 0, temp2 = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < 25; row++){
      for (int col = 0; col < 25; col++){
        if (row == shoot[0] && col == shoot[1])
        {
          check[row][0] = shoot[0];
          check[row][col] = shoot[1];
          temp1 = row;
          temp2 = col;
        }
      }
    }

    if (check[temp1][0] == ships[temp1][0] && check[temp1][temp2] == ships[temp1][temp2])
    {
      System.out.print("You have already entered that location!");
    }

    shoot[0]--;
    shoot[1]--;

  }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what your asking or trying to do.  Why are you trying to make a two dimensional array from shoot?  Also, what does ships[][] have in it (I assume it has the location of the players ships)?  Shouldn't you check to see if the value at `ships[shoot[0]][shoot[1]] == 1` or whatever your ship present indicator is?

Comment: take a step back and think what you WANT to do first. Then break your objective into smaller steps. The code, as you have it, only asks the user for the row and col, validating if they are negative or if both are zero. It is not validating if they are over 5. Work on that and ask a specific question every time.

Comment: I'm trying to create a code that will store all of the previous shoot location in a 2d array.  Then I can check that array with user next shoot, and if the user wants to shoot at the same location I can alert them.

Comment: @SkyToken, start with what Alexandre said (visualize what you want to do; check if the shot is off the board the other direction).  You'll need to figure out where to store your data (you need either a parameter with the last shots or a global).  Next you might want to reconsider how you store the data (is there maybe [something](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) that provides a coordinate in a simpler easier to use fashion than an array? also, is there a [dynamic size](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) storage object you could use?)

Comment: The other problem you have is I don't see where you are storing the locations of the ships. You could probably make this more efficient if you added a class called Ship and then had different classes of Battleships. From there, you could have hits, hit locations, etc

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure about what you want to do, but, if `shoot[0]` and `shoot[1]` do represent the x and y of the shooting location as I'm suspecting, then maybe it's as simple as the following :

When you've checked if the location is in reliable bounds, then either you set ships to a different state, at said location :

`ships[shoot[0]][shoot[1]] = HIT; // or MISSED if there was no ship here`

or you use an entire new array to record the shootings (I think it was what you intended) :

`hasAlreadyShot[shoot[0]][shoot[1]] = true;`

depending of your programming style and choices.

Then, whenever the player chooses a new target, you can check if it has not already been a previous choice.

Comment: I think you are heading the right way. I will try it out and get back to you if worked.